# How can I repeat chained animation in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uikit, xcode11

I would like to animate the whole chain for forever.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.2, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.circleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 9, y: 9)
    }) { (_) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.circleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it up inside a method:

```
func repeatingAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.2, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.circleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 9, y: 9)
    }) { (_) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.circleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.repeatingAnimation()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't it cause memory leak?

Comment: @MaricVikike No, I added a capture list and captured self as weak, because else you do get indeed a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the two animations within a keyframe animation. Then you can `.repeat` that:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 4.4, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: { 
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 2.0/4.4) { 
        self.circleImageView.transform = .init(scaleX: 9, y: 9)
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 2.0/4.4) { 
        self.circleImageView.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
    }
})
```